# Cannot read property 'props' of undefined ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting error "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" in ReactJS. 
I want to route the page to another page after login and also pass the user token for the session till logout for my app.
My code :

```
    ...
    import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
    import { EventList } from "../EventList/EventList";

    export class SignIn extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          fields: {
            username: '',
            password: ''
          },
          errors: {}
        }
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
      }
      ...
      onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(this.handleValidation()){
          var apiBaseUrl = "http://api.eventsacross-stage.railsfactory.com/api/";
          var input = this.state.fields;
          axios.post(apiBaseUrl+'v1/users/signin', input)
          .then(function (response) {
             console.log(response);
             if(response.data.status == 200){
               console.log("Login successful");
               alert("Login successful");
               this.props.router.push('/EventList');
             }
             else if(...
             }
           })...
           });
         }
      }
    ...
      render() {
        return (
          ...
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Sign In</button>
...
        );
      }
    }

    export default withRouter(SignIn);
```

Comment: Can you at least point what line is breaking? Where is onSubmit being called?

Comment: this.props.router.push('/EventList');

Comment: Please edit your post to show that. Also, put the code where onSubmit is being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside `then` function has a value different than `this` of `onSubmit` function.
You can read more about `this` behaviour over here: [this|MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

For this to work, you should store correct `this` value in another variable, just like @thomas-lin said:

```
onSubmit(e){
  var that = this;
  // ...
  // later, on axios call:
  axios.post(apiBaseUrl+'v1/users/signin', input)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    if(response.data.status == 200){
      console.log("Login successful");
      alert("Login successful");
      that.props.router.push('/EventList');
    }
    else if(...) {
      //...
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

As it has been pointed out by @astorga, you have wrong context for 'this'. But I would recommend using Arrow Function instead of storing 'that' variable.

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.handleValidation()){
        var apiBaseUrl = "http://api.eventsacross-stage.railsfactory.com/api/";
        var input = this.state.fields;
        axios.post(apiBaseUrl+'v1/users/signin', input)
          .then((response) => { // Arrow function here, which doesn't create new 'this' scope
             if(response.data.status == 200) {
               this.props.router.push('/EventList');
             }
             else if(...
             }
          });
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the wrong use of "this" that lead to this mistake,try the code like this:

```js
onSubmit(e){
  var that = this
  .....
  that.props.router.push('/EventList');

}
```